# Is passing a pair of long long in set find safe?

Tags: c++, set, std-pair, stdset

I have the following code:

```
std::set<std::pair<int, int>> my_set;

long long x = (some value);
long long y = (some value);

// should be true if x or y exceed the limits of int
bool z = my_set.find({x, y}) == my_set.end();
```

It works without any errors and seems to work correctly. But, I wonder if it's 'safe' because I am passing a pair of `long long` to the `find` function.

Thanks!

Comment: What if the values are bigger than the maximum value of int?

Comment: It is safe as long no narrowing conversion occurs, but that only depends on the values of `x` and `y` and is totally unrelated to `std::set`. I.e. make `x` and `y` `int`s and you're fine, or make `my_set` of type `std::set<std::pair<long long, long long>>`

Comment: If you know the items in the set can't contain the values you are searching for because they won't fit in an `int` then why are you searching? Feels like an XY problem.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I don't know if the value in `x` or `y` contains value bigger than that allowed in `int`. Of course, I can compare with the bounds of `int`, but I just wondered if I can do it without that.

Comment: You could use [gsl::narrow](https://github.com/microsoft/GSL/blob/main/include/gsl/narrow)

Comment: I think it will work correctly if you use `std::less<>` as the set comparator instead of the default `std::less<std::pair<int, int>>` (C++14 required). This will prevent the conversion from `long long` to `int` and compare them directly instead.

Comment: You should check to make sure the x and y are within bounds of min/max int.  Otherwise it will not be safe.

Comment: @interjay No, the conversion happens already to construct a temporary `pair` object for the parameter of `find`. The overloads for transparent search can't be used because braced arguments can't be deduced.

Comment: @user17732522 If you use `std::less<>` then it will use overload 3 or 4 of [`find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/find) which doesn't perform a conversion.

Comment: @interjay They are not viable for braced-init-list arguments. You'll have to give the argument a proper type as well.

Comment: @user17732522 You're right, I missed that. Then you would also need to explicitly create a `std::pair`.

Comment: It depends on your definition of “safe”. The values will be converted to `int`. If the values are out of range for an `int` the code might not do what you want. But that’s also true if `x` and `y` are both `int`s; if you give them values that are out of range the code might not do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not safe in as far as the values that will actually be compared may not be what you expect.

The two `long long` values will be converted to `int` and then `find` will look for a `pair` containing these two converted `int` values. Since C++20 it is guaranteed that this conversion produces the unique value represented by `int` that is equal to the original value modulo 2 to the power of the width of `int`.

If the values of `x` and `y` will fall outside the range of `int`, this means that `z` may become `false` even though there may not be a pair in the set for which the values of `x` and `y` are (mathematically) equal to those of the pair in the set.

However, aside from that, there is nothing wrong. The search after conversion from `long long` to `int` will work exactly as expected.

Comment: Thank you for answering. If I understand correctly, if `x` and `y` are outside the bounds, they will be converted to `int`s and then checked. So, there is a risk that `z` becomes `true` (because the new pair may be in the set) but the chances of the exact pair being in the set is small. Do I understand correctly?

Comment: @MangoPizza `z` is `false` if the set is found. It is `true` when it is not found. Whether the chance is small or not depends heavily on what values your program happens to produce for `x` and `y` and the elements in the set. It could happen all the time. You can't just say that it is unlikely. Otherwise correct.

Comment: _but the chances of the exact pair being in the set is small_ But not zero.  That's exactly the kind of random bug you don't want.

Comment: @PaulSanders I think you wanted to tag MangoPizza?

Comment: @user17732522 Thanks, but did I need to?  I thought that the OP gets notified anyway.

Comment: @PaulSanders OP of the thing you comment on yes, but not the question OP for a comment on an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing a pair of `long long` to the function. Since you did not specify the type of the key passed to [`std::set::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/find), the compiler uses the constructor taking a lvalue reference to a const Key object, i.e. in this case `std::pair<int, int>`.

This comes with all drawbacks of you creating a `std::pair<int, int>` from values that may exceed the range of `int`.

```
std::set<std::pair<int, int>> my_set;

my_set.emplace(0, 0);

long long x = 0x100000000;
long long y = 0;

// should be false if x or y exceed the limits of int
bool z = my_set.find({ x, y }) == my_set.end();
std::cout << std::boolalpha << z << '\n'; // prints false
```

Comment: Isn't `template< class K > iterator find( const K& x ); (3) (since C++14)` a better match? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/find

Comment: @RichardCritten The type for the template parameter cannot be deduced, since the expression `{x, y}` has no type info attached, so the only option for the compiler here is to construct a key object given the non-template member function which takes `std::pair<int, int> const&`.